# the difference among "what do/shall/will we do (now)?" in a specific situation

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-difference

In this situation, is there any difference between these three expressions?

The situation is as follows.

> You and your friend are hanging out.
>   You guys went to a cafe and enjoyed talking there for some time.
>   As you and your friend are getting out of the cafe, you are not sure what to do next.
>   You can suggest going to a movie theater or just depart and go home or whatever.
>   So you are saying one of the three expressions below.

1. What do we do (now)?
2. What shall we do (now)?
3. What will we do (now)?

Thank you as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Shall" and "will" mean basically the same thing -- they are referring to the future. The traditional grammar rule is that "shall" is only used with the first person ("I" or "we"), and "will" is used in all other cases -- but nobody actually *follows* this "rule" with any consistency. Effectively, "shall" and "will" are interchangeable, except "shall" sounds a little more formal.

(Here's a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_and_will) about "shall" vs. "will".)

"What do we do now" is in the present tense, and is the most correct of the three options, since the speaker is talking about actions in the present. "Will" and "shall" are future tense -- so "will" is correct if you are asking, "What will we do after the movie?"

Comment: I think I'd be more inclined to use _should_ before I'd use _do, will_, or _shall_.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, Matt Cline. You said ***What will we do now*** is incorrect because of the wrong tense. But I would like to know how wrong that sentence sounds to native English speakers. And is ***What will we do*** with ***now*** dropped out correct?

Comment: @J.R. Thank you. Then, is there any difference in meaning or nuances between the use of should and the use of will or shall in that sentence?

Comment: @SmartHumanism: it's all about making sure your tense matches what you are trying to say.
If you are talking about the future, then "What will we do?" is correct.

"What will we do now?" is incorrect because "now" is talking about the present, but "will" is the future tense. In contrast, "What will we do tomorrow?" is correct, because "tomorrow" agrees with the future tense.
 

As far as "how wrong does it sound", this is a relatively minor error. I think a native speaker would understand the sentence. But that doesn't mean it's correct. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the kind answering again, Matt Cline. Now I understand what you're explaining clearly. You said the error is minor so that a native English speaker would understand it with no problem. But I would like to know how weird that sentence, which is ***What will we do now***, could sound to a native English speaker. I try to study how weird certain expressions sound so that I can get the insight to manage a flawless conversation.

Comment: @SmartHumanism -- I'm not sure what you're asking that I haven't already covered. There isn't an objective scale of "weirdness" that I can point you to.

Comment: @MattCline I mean how weird ***What will we do now*** would sound to a native English speaker. You said that there will be no problem for a native speaker to understand that sentence, so I would like to go deeper than that. There are certain expressions that there is no problem to understand but that sound definitely a little weird to native English speaker's ear. :) I appreciate all your answers.

Comment: I am so sorry that I am bothering you too much, but I mean, as a matter of feeling, not as a matter of reasoning or logic, how would you immediately feel when you hear ***What will we do now***? Would you feel it is a little weird right away? Or only after thinking and reasoning about that sentence, would you find it wrong? I know how it is logically and grammatically, but it is a natural feeling that I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

All three expressions are common and valid, but:

> What do we do now?

is typically a question asked when people are in trouble and wondering what action to take:

> It's nearly dark and we're hopelessly lost; what do we do now?

The distinction between **will** and **shall** has long since been lost for the great majority of native English speakers. However, it's easier to ask **what will we do now?** (what 'ill we do now?) and thus the more likely construction when people are speaking to one another.

The bottom line is that all three are asking the same question. You can use which ever comes to mind.

Comment: According to Google Ngram, "What do you want to do now?" (related: "What do you feel like doing now?" has surpassed "What will we do now?" and "What shall we do now?", which matches my experiences of common speech.

Comment: Thank you so much, for the kind answer which is very helpful a lot by sorting out. :)